# Regex to stop at a specific character

Tags: regex, linux, bash, grep

I have output that looks like this:

```
 16    1VirtualMachine1         [aljkas] some_data.blah
 17       Virtual Machine 1        [jklaj] some_more_data.blah
 23    Virtu al Machin e 1      [adwv] some_more_data.blah


 12     Virtual_Machine one      [awa] some_more_data.blah
 11    VirtualMa chineone       [kladfsa] some_more_data.blah
```

And I want to get just the content between the spaces and up to `[`.

So output that would return just:

```
1VirtualMachine1
Virtual Machine 1
Virtu al Machin e 1
Virtual_Machine one
VirtualMa chineone
```

My regex looks like this (but is not doing what I think it should):

`a_cmd | grep -o -E '[[:space:]]{2,}[a-zA-Z0-9\.,_()]+.+[[:space:]]{2,}'`

And this just returns all of the original output.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like your input is delimited by character-count. Why don't you just grab from characters 7-32 and then strip whitespace, like `cut -c7-32`?

Comment: Because the names can be very long or very short and impact the placement of the `[` in my output :(

Comment: Please edit the question so your example input has this characteristic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk 'NF{ gsub(/(^[[:space:]]*[[:digit:]]+[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+\[.*)/,""); print}' file
1VirtualMachine1
Virtual Machine 1
Virtu al Machin e 1
Virtual_Machine one
VirtualMa chineone
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `sed`:

```
sed 's/[0-9 ]* \(.*\)\[.*/\1/;/^$/d' your.file
```

Answer (score 2):

this grep line would do the job:

```
grep -oP '\d\s+\K[^[]*'
```

with your example:

```
kent$  echo " 16    1VirtualMachine1         [aljkas] some_data.blah
 17    Virtual Machine 1        [jklaj] some_more_data.blah
 23    Virtu al Machin e 1      [adwv] some_more_data.blah


 12    Virtual_Machine one      [awa] some_more_data.blah
 11    VirtualMa chineone       [kladfsa] some_more_data.blah"|grep -oP '\d\s+\K[^[]*'
1VirtualMachine1         
Virtual Machine 1        
Virtu al Machin e 1      
Virtual_Machine one      
VirtualMa chineone
```